# "Trim unused code" grayed and selected in VS

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I am trying out a dotnet 8 asp.net core api template on a linux-arm device, hence I need to publish it. This works as expected except for one thing: I can't have my code trimmed because I need SignalR, and that one uses a marker interface, that is not only internal but also empty, hence will definitely be trimmed away.

[image]

But I can't unselect it. I haven't found the `pubxml` tag for it either. How can I convince it not to trim?

[image]

*[Update]*
I have found the tag, but seems not to affect the checkbox..
`<PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>`

For now, I have recreated the project from another template that does not result in graying out this checkbox...